# How do I open a picture after creating it in C#?

Tags: c#, image, file-io

I'm writing a simple program to convert text to strings. One quick question, how can I open the image once I finished creating that? I don't want to have pictureBox in the program.

Comment: Open the picture in what exactly?

Comment: And what image are you opening?

Comment: Not sure what it means to "convert text to strings" either.  You mean text in an image, i.e., OCR?

Comment: Please read this article first: [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you're asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am *assuming* you mean that you want to load your image into your application without having to physically store it in a property inside of a PictureBox.  To do so, you can use *Bitmap.FromFile*  e.g.

```
var myBitmap = Bitmap.FromFile("c:\somefile.bmp");
```

This is given that you are are creating and then *saving* your image to an path on the file system.